# Fire a function on keypress if there are no inputs selected

Tags: jquery, input, focus

I am new to jQuery and am trying to fire a function on a keyPress if there are NO inputs selected.  I am having trouble with testing for focus.  Below is what I currently have but it isn't working correctly.  Any advice?

```
var inputHasFocus = false;
$('#myForm :input').each(is(":focus")){
    inputHasFocus = true;
};

if (inputHasFocus == false){

    $("*").keypress(function (e) {
        // the function
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var focusedInputs = $("#myForm input:focus");
if (focusedInputs != null && focusedInputs.length > 0) { inputHasFocus = true; }
```

Something like that.

Comment: Thanks Plan B worked great once I put it inside the keypress.  It looks like the other response would work as well but I tried this first and it worked so I didn't try the other.  Thanks to both of you!

$("*").keypress(function (e) {
 var inputHasFocus = false;
 var focusedInputs = $("#myForm input:focus");
 if (focusedInputs != null && focusedInputs.length > 0) { 
 inputHasFocus = true; }
 if(inputHasFocus != true) {
  // the function to run each time a key is pressed with no input selected
       }
 }
});

Answer (score 1):

I would try it as follows:

```
var inputHasFocus = false;

$('#myForm :input').focus(function() {
    inputHasFocus = true; // Set true if a Form-Field is selected
}).blur(function() {
    inputHasFocus = false; // Set false if a Form-Field has left
});

$("*").keypress(function() {
    if(!inputHasFocus) {
        // check if(inputHasFocus) after the keypress has done
        // otherwise you have the basic value in the var inputHasFocus 
        // here you can run your function...
    }
});
```

jQuery Documentation-Links to the used functions:

- [.focus()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/focus)
- [.blur()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/blur#fn)
- [.keypress()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/keypress#fn)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like this:

```
var inputHasFocus = false;

$('#myForm input').each(function () {

 if ($(this).is(":focus")) {
  inputHasFocus = true;
 }

};
```

Comment: Pretty much exactly what snuffer.ch suggested except without the blur.